# SVN - Is creating branch from branch from branch on and on wrong?

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-strategy, svn-trunk

**Situation**: 
I have seen a practice where SVN branches are created from branches and keep on going. For example: Branch1 was created from TRUNK; Branch2 from Branch1; etc. See below to get an idea:

*....goes on and on.......**Branch4**--from--> **Branch3**--from--> **Branch2**--from--> **Branch1**--from-->**Trunk**.*

So each new branch is created from the latest branch; instead of creating it from Trunk or Main.

**Questions**:

1. Is this kind of practice faulty?
2. Will this cause issues?
3. Is this kind of practice followed anywhere?

**Update**:
First and third questions have satisfactory answers. Thanks for the help.
Are there any issues to be wary of in particular while following this method?

Comment: SVN is a tool that can support very different use cases, and there might be use cases for which this is a good solution. That means: First describe your use cases. Then it's easy to explain, how you can support your use cases with SVN.

Comment: I see. I just wanted to make sure that the practice is not wrong per se. I get that depending on the requirements this can be right (or not). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this kind of practice faulty?

No.

> Will this cause issues?

No *new types* of issues for "here and back" merges, compared to "trunk-mediator" case, but (possible) *N old types (where N is amount of synchronized branches)

> Is this kind of practice followed anywhere?

Probably yes - it's rather common case and doesn't have anything exotic and irrational

---

**Note**: I think, using SVN 1.8 automatic merges give you a noticeable amount of benefits in the amount of needed operations in final reintegration, comparing to pre-1.8 `merge --reitegrate`

Comment: This pretty much answers my questions. As long as it is not outright wrong, I will dig deep and find the reasons/advantages (if any) for such a practice. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the *N old type issues?